# Dados não estão sendo gravados no BD por PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou estudando PHP orientado a objetos e, a partir de alguns tutoriais retirados da net (pdo, pojo, Dao...), fiz um sistema bem simples no qual pego o valor inserido no `<input type="text">` e gravo no banco de dados.

Aliás, deveria fazer isso. O grande problema é esse, não está gravando o registro. Coloquei um `echo` no html com a variável para ver se pelo menos estava pegando, e sim, está, mas no bd não grava...

É alguma coisa errada no meu arquivo de conexão ou classe? No momento eu acho que não estou instanciando certo o `inserir`, seria isso?

**PS**: Mais para frente quero armazenar o caminho de imagem ou vídeo, tipo um mini gerenciador de galeria de imagens por isso estou usando aquele foreach no teste.php

São os seguintes arquivos: `conexao.php`, `classes.php`, `funcoes.php` e `teste.php`.

---

**conexao.php**

```php
class Conexao {
    public static $instance;
    private function __construct() {
        //
    }
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nomedobd', 'root', '',
 array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

**classes.php**

```php
    class Imagem {

    private $id;
    private $nome;
    private $caminho;
    private $tipo_obj;

    public function getId_img() {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getNome_img() {
        return $this->nome;
    }
    public function getCaminho_img() {
       // return $this->caminho;
        return $this->caminho;
    }
    public function getTipo_obj() {
       // return $this->tipo_obj;
        return $this->tipo;
    }
    public function setNome($nome) {
        /* $this->id = $id_img;
        $this->nome = $nome_img;
        $this->caminho = $caminho_img;
        $this->tipo_obj = $tipo_obj; */
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
    public function setCaminho($nome) {
        $this->caminho = $nome;
    }
    public function setTipo($nome) {
        $this->tipo = $nome;
    }

}
```

**funcoes.php**

```php
    require_once "conexao.php";
require_once "geralog.php";
require_once "classes.php";

class DaoImagem {

    public static $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        //
    }
    function inputText($nome) {
            return "<input type='text' id='$nome' name='$nome' value='$nome' />";
    }
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
            self::$instance = new DaoImagem();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function Inserir(Imagem $nome){
        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO imagem (        
                tipo,
                nome,
                caminho) 
                VALUES (
                :tipo,
                :nome,
                :caminho)";

            $p_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
            $p_sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome->getNome_img());
           // $p_sql->bindValue(":nome", $imagem->getNome_img());
            $p_sql->bindValue(":caminho", $nome->getNome_img());
           // $p_sql->bindValue(":caminho", $imagem->getCaminho_img());
            $p_sql->bindValue(":tipo", $nome->getNome_img());
           // $p_sql->bindValue(":tipo", $imagem->getTipo_obj());
            return $p_sql->execute();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar executar esta ação, foi gerado
 um LOG do mesmo, tente novamente mais tarde.";
            GeraLog::getInstance()->inserirLog("Erro: Código: " . $e->getCode() . " Mensagem: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**teste.php**

```php
        <?php 

include_once('funcoes_imagem.php');




/* foreach ($_FILES["files"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "public/$name");
    }
} */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="pt-br">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <?php $nome = new DaoImagem(); ?>
            <?php echo $nome->inputText('nome',$_POST['nome']);?>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
            //$nome = new DaoImagem();
            $envia = new DaoImagem();
            //echo $_POST['nome'];
            print $envia->Inserir($nome);
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Desde já, obrigado.

## Último ajuste:

**Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DaoImagem::Inserir() must be an instance of Imagem, instance of DaoImagem given, called in C:\wamp\www\SistemaUpload\teste2.php on line 34 and defined in C:\wamp\www\SistemaUpload\funcoes_imagem.php on line 25**

Comment: Pra começar, altere o comando "SET nome utf8" para "SET NAMES utf8". Tem como colar pra gente a(s) mensagem(ns) de erro?

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta. Tenho aqui o log de erro do php... linha 5 e 29 do teste2.php (teste.php no caso), que é no meu if e onde ele imprime o input na tela...

Comment: [18-Jan-2017 17:41:37 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: PHP_SELF in C:\wamp\www\SistemaUpload\teste2.php on line 27

[18-Jan-2017 17:41:37 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Stack trace:

[18-Jan-2017 17:41:37 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\SistemaUpload\teste2.php:0

[18-Jan-2017 17:41:41 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: PHP_SELF in C:\wamp\www\SistemaUpload\teste2.php on line 27

[18-Jan-2017 17:41:41 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Stack trace:

[18-Jan-2017 17:41:41 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\SistemaUpload\teste2.php:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente consegui... depois de apanhar bastante, descobri que tinha uns erros no na classe funcoes_imagem e no teste precisava instanciar mais uma classe e definir os metodos... Vai aqui o resultado, talvez possa ajudar outras pessoas:

```
conexão.php (não foi alterado)
```

funcoes_imagem.php

```
    require_once "conexao.php";
    require_once "geralog.php";
    require_once "classes.php";

    class DaoImagem {

        public static $instance;

        public function __construct() {
            //
        }
        function inputText($nome) {
                return "<input type='text' id='$nome' name='$nome' value='$nome' />";
        }
        public static function getInstance() {
            if (!isset(self::$instance))
                self::$instance = new DaoImagem();

            return self::$instance;
        }

        public function Inserir(Imagem $nomeCerto){
            try {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO imagem (        
                    tipo,
                    nome,
                    caminho) 
                    VALUES (
                    :tipo,
                    :nome,
                    :caminho)";

                $p_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
                $p_sql->bindValue(":nome", $nomeCerto->getNome_img());
               // $p_sql->bindValue(":nome", $imagem->getNome_img());
                $p_sql->bindValue(":caminho", $nomeCerto->getNome_img());
               // $p_sql->bindValue(":caminho", $imagem->getCaminho_img());
                $p_sql->bindValue(":tipo", $nomeCerto->getNome_img());
               // $p_sql->bindValue(":tipo", $imagem->getTipo_obj());
                return $p_sql->execute();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                print "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar executar esta ação, foi gerado
     um LOG do mesmo, tente novamente mais tarde.";
                GeraLog::getInstance()->inserirLog("Erro: Código: " . $e->getCode() . " Mensagem: " . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

teste.php

```
<?php 
include_once('funcoes_imagem.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="pt-br">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <?php $nome = new DaoImagem(); ?>
            <?php //echo $nome->inputText('nome',$_POST['nome']);?>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
            $nomeCerto = new Imagem();
            $nomeCerto->setNome($_POST['nome']);
            //$nome = new DaoImagem();
            $envia = new DaoImagem();
            //echo $_POST['nome'];
            print $nome->Inserir($nomeCerto);
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para corrigir o erro que você mencionou no comentário, deixe o seu formulário da seguinte forma:

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
       <?php $formulario = new DaoImagem(); ?>
       <?php echo $formulario->inputText('nome',$_POST['nome']);?>
       <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>`

Depois, vi que você mencionou o parâmetro ':id_img' em sua string sql, mas não adicionou valor a ele com com bindValue(). Dê uma olhada nisso também.

Comment: Olá Luiz, obrigado pela resposta... O formulário ontem depois de postar vi que faltou o $_server[]... mas a sql já até mudei, pois como a id é PK e automatica, removi da string sql, ficando assim:
INSERT INTO imagem (tipo, nome,caminho) VALUES (:tipo,:nome,:caminho)